# whats the best/recommended RESTful way to handle large single Json response?

Tags: json, rest

When we have many documents to be returned from the response, we can paginate the result and give the link in the response to retrieve the next set of documents to be fetched from the API. However my case is different, each document in my response can be very large. How do I deal with such response ?
For Example consider the sample Json below:

```
{
  "excludes": null,
  "endDate": 1422918663,
  "appliedText": "Applied  text",
  "id": "135699543",
...
  "assignedTo": {
    "productPart": [
      {
        "part": "1"
      },
      {
        "part": "2"
      },
      {
        "part": "3"
      },
      {
        "part": "4"
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
...
}
```

If you see here, the `productPart` can grow to tens of thousands. How can I restrict such large response yet retain the structure.

Comment: what is the problem with such large response? Performance, memory issue?

Comment: @dit yes it might lead to both performance and memory issue. Our API consumers might might take a lot of time in reading and parsing the json. UI gets affected badly.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch product parts with a separate request (if you have the possibility) which then in turn can be paginated.

Alt. return the first x product parts and then provide a link where more product parts can be obtained.

Comment: Yea thought about both options, 1) first is not possible as product parts alone cannot be fetched 2) product parts in the response are not sorted. If we enable sorting in product parts section, it might take more time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try something like [JSON-Streaming](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi).

> Streaming Processing (also known as Incremental Processing) is the most efficient way to process JSON content. It has the lowest memory and processing overhead, and can often match performance of many binary data formats available on Java platform

Here is the main idea:

```
try {

    InputStream in    = [..];
    JsonParser parser = new JsonFactory().createParser(in);
    JsonToken token   = null;

    while ((token = parser.nextToken()) == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) {
       /*
        * Parse parts and store them in client DB
        * use later client side pagination 
        *
        * {
        *    "part": "i"
        * }
        */
    }

 } catch (Exception e) {
    //
 }
```